# I got Method Illuminate\Routing\Router::uniqueMiddleware does not exist. after I run php artisan to create migration table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

**Exception:**
BadMethodCallException
Method Illuminate\Routing\Router::uniqueMiddleware does not exist.

**laravel given solution:**

Bad Method Call
Did you mean Illuminate\Routing\Router::getMiddleware() ?

**StackTrack**

Illuminate\Routing\Router::__callStatic
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/Macroable.php:77

---

public static function __callStatic($method, $parameters)

```
{

    if (! static::hasMacro($method)) {

        throw new BadMethodCallException(sprintf(

            'Method %s::%s does not exist.', static::class, $method

        ));

    }



    $macro = static::$macros[$method];



    if ($macro instanceof Closure) {

        $macro = $macro->bindTo(null, static::class);

    }



    return $macro(...$parameters);

}
```

Comment: what are you doing involving 'unique'?

Comment: Can you post your migration(s) file(s) and routes\console.php?

Comment: @Rithy Sam show us the ``web.php`` file maybe you are implementing a midddleware in any of the route which does not exist.